# How to mock a method without a parameter list with ScalaMock 5.0.0?

Tags: scala, unit-testing, scalamock

When trying to mock a method declared as

```
def foo: Int
```

with

```
val mock = mock[MyClass]
(mock.foo _).expects().returning(10)
```

I get an error
`` Error: Methods without a parameter list and by-name params can no longer be converted to functions as `m _`, write a function literal `() => m` instead ``

There's a tip to write a function literal instead but I don't quite understand how to convert my code into an equivalent function literal.

Comment: Would `() => mock.foo` not work? That's what it looks like the error message is asking for (not tested it though)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nice to see people using ScalaMock 5 already!
Our test case in the unit tests looks like this:

Trait:

```
def noParamMethod(): String
```

related test for it:

```
(() => mockedTrait.noParamMethod()).expects().returning("yey")
```

It's here in the code:
https://github.com/paulbutcher/ScalaMock/blob/master/shared/src/test/scala/org/scalamock/test/mockable/TestTrait.scala

and the test for it:
https://github.com/paulbutcher/ScalaMock/blob/22c26174bfb99b403af2be38ab35cabfe58f4c5f/shared/src/test/scala/org/scalamock/test/scalatest/BasicTest.scala#L39

Worth mentioning that this should only be needed for Scala 2.13 to satisfy compiler changes in that version.

Comment: Thanks for answer but I didn't ask about method with empty parameter list (with empty parentheses) but without it (no parentheses at all). Method with empty parameter list doesn't produce that error. I will test it tomorrow though, maybe I missed something :)

Comment: Seems that I oversimplified my example. I mark the answer as accepted because it answers the question. In my case the problem was that foo was called in the constructor of MyClass so the line `(mock.foo _).expects().returning(10)` was never executed because of exception in previous line.